# What is the proper way to declare boolean as property in php7.4

Tags: php

I have this class

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    private boolean $postImagesUploaded;

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->postImagesUploaded = true;
    }
}
```

as you can see I declared a private property `$postImagesUploaded`

and somewhere in `store()` method I assigned it with a value of `true`

yet I got the error saying

> [10-Oct-2020 13:45:30 Asia/Manila] PHP TypeError:  Typed property
> PostController::$postImagesUploaded must be an
> instance of Controllers\boolean, bool used in
> /path/to/PostController.php on line 51

So what is the right/proper way of declaring datatype for boolean in php class?

I am aware it could be just

```
private $postImagesUploaded = false;
```

what I am trying here is to strictly declare a datatype for `$postImagesUploaded`

so that I can't be assigned with any other values other than boolean

Comment: it should be ``bool``. using ``boolean`` will refer to the class name

Comment: See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types). Valid type declaration for `Boolean` variable is `bool`.